# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException ReadingFiles

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadingFiles {

    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner("C:\\Users\\adamp\\Desktop\\test\\chinese.txt");
        }//try
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }//catch
    }//openFile()

    public void readFile(){
        while(x.hasNext()){
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a,b,c);
        }//while
    }//readFile()

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }//closeFile()

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ReadingFiles cz = new ReadingFiles();
        cz.openFile();
        cz.readFile();
        cz.closeFile();
    }//main
}//class
```

Hey i am learning java and i have no idea why it keeps giving me an Error
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" I would really appreciate if someone explained to me why is this happening.

Comment: You're testing `x.hasNext()`, but then trying to pull three items from the scanner.  It looks like you're reaching a point where there are fewer than three items available from your scanner.  If there are (for example) 2 items left, `x.hasNext()` will return true, but your third `x.next()` will throw a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: `new Scanner("C:\\Users\\adamp\\Desktop\\test\\chinese.txt");` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Well i have 12 items in the File, and I am following a tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RNYUKxAgmw) so i don't know if thats the case. Maybe the tutorial is outdated or something. Can you recommend a good tutorial on writing to Files and reading in from Files. thanks

Comment: Did you visit duplicate link on top of your question (you may need to reload this tab to see it)? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks i solved it by looking at other threads

Answer (score 0):

you are calling x.next() 3 times, you should only call it once

Comment: so how should it look like if i want to print it 3 items in a row and then next collumn